# Avoid multiple form submission

Tags: jsf-2

In JSF2, is there any way to handle the multiple form submit (user clicks submit button multiple times)? Now we are getting the below exception in server

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response already committed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response already committed
javax.faces.FacesException: socket write error: Connection aborted by peer
```

Comment: java.net.SocketException: socket write error: Connection aborted by peer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on how you're submitting the form. If you're using `<f:ajax>` or any other Ajax based tag to perform the submit by Ajax, then your best bet is to use `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent()` to add a function which disables the button when the Ajax request is about to be sent and re-enables it after the Ajax response is retrieved.

E.g. as follows, which you include after the JSF Ajax scripts are included, e.g. inside a `<script>` or `<h:outputScript>` referring a `.js` file in `<h:head>`.

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) {
    if (data.source.type != "submit") {
        return; // Ignore anything else than input type="submit".
    }

    switch (data.status) {
        case "begin":
            data.source.disabled = true; // Disable input type="submit".
            break;
        case "complete":
            data.source.disabled = false; // Re-enable input type="submit".
            break;
    }    
});
```

If you're *not* using Ajax to perform the submit, then one of the ways is to throw in a `setTimeout()` function in `onclick` which disables the button a few ms after click.

Basically,

```
<h:commandButton 
    id="foo"
    value="submit"
    action="#{bean.submit}"
    onclick="setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'' + this.id + '\').disabled=true;', 50);"
/>
```

The `setTimeout()` is mandatory, because when you disable it immediately, then the `name=value` pair of the button won't be sent along with the request which would cause JSF to be unable to identify the `action` to be executed. You can of course refactor it to some DOM ready or window onload function which applies this for all submit buttons (jQuery would be tremendously helpful in this).

Comment: Do you some pointers or links for making it as DOM Ready or Window onload function.

Comment: Sorry, it does not need to be executed during DOM ready or window onload. Just put it unmodified in a `<script>` or `<h:outputScript>` in `<h:head>`.

Comment: Thanks BaluCs...we can find the submit buttons usings the Style.

Comment: Isn't there a more standard way to do this? Maybe doing this in the server side with p:commandButton?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a disabled button on the page which does nothing and show it when the submit button is clicked.

```
<div id="disabled" style="display:none;">
     <span class="disabled-button"/>
</div>
<div id="enabled" style="display:block;">
     <span class="enabled-button">
          <h:commandLink id="submit"/>
     </span>
</div>


$('#submit').live("click", function() {
$('#enabled').hide();
$('#disabled').show();
});
```